# Can't see detailed Spring Boot transaction information in NewRelic

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic

I have a Spring Boot 3.1.5 application base on Java 17, dockerized and executed in a Kubernetes 1.27.x cluster on AKS. I use the New Relic Java agent v8.7.0.

I plugged the NewRelic java agent and I saw metrics in the UI.

When I select a transaction, I can see the details about external api calls or database query but I can't see any information on my own code.

[image]

How can I have my code automatically instrumented?

Answer (score 1):

New Relic's Java agent will out of the box instrument code from libraries/frameworks that it can recognize.

Unfortunately, it cannot automatically instrument the rest of your code because this would lead to too much overhead. For instance, if all your getters are instrumented it would add the processing for each of them. Also it would show all of them in that trace, making it too much noise there.

To improve the visibility of your own code, you can add custom instrumentation, either by [annotations](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/api-guides/java-agent-api-instrument-using-annotation/), [XML](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/java-instrumentation-xml/) or the [Custom instrumentation editor](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/custom-instrumentation-editor-instrument-ui/).

To instrument your methods using annotations, you'd need to add a dependency to `newrelic-api` in your project, then simply add an annotation to the method you want visibility in:

```
@Trace
public String method() {
  // do things
}
```

For XML, you craft a file and add to a `extensions` folder in the same folder as your agent jar. Here is an abridged example of such file:

```
...
<instrumentation metricPrefix="EXAMPLE">
   <pointcut transactionStartPoint="true">
     <className>full.path.to.MyClass</className>
     <method>
       <name>myMethod</name>
     </method>
   </poincut>
</instrumentation>
...
```

Comment: I tried to add a custom instrumentation with the UI. I select "Class method by signature", then I enter my class with the full package path (ex: com.example.drive.core.StorageController) and in the method input I enter the method name (ex: download). Then I deploy this configuration. After few seconds, I saw in the newrelic log file this message "The method download with parameter type () on class com.example.drive.core.StorageController is not present and therefore will never match anything.".

Comment: Does the method receive parameters? I am not sure how well the instrumentation UI works with parameters. I know that XML, if you don't specify parameters, it will instrument all matching methods. It is also possible that there is something else interfering with the New Relic agent. We've seen problems with some beans that are generated with cglib.

Comment: I tried with parameters in UI, with XML with and without parameters with no success. The only thing which works for me is with newrelic java sdk and Trace annotations but I must put them on all sub-methods calls to have a complete call instrumented. This is very inconvenient. Is there another way to proceed?